Move grid element to the empty space
I want to move the third div using css into the upper empty space. Every element has it is own height. How can I do it?
<div class="grid">
  <div style="height: fit-content;">1</div>
  <div style="height: 50px;">2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>

.grid {
    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  
    gap: 10px;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}


